# How to return pointer to array of struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I created a struct of `student` inside the function using `malloc` and populated it with data. I want to return the address of the array of struct back to `main` and print it line by line, but with my implementation, it is not printing. I debugged my code and indeed, it is able to return the address of my array to `main`. I don't know why it's not printing though. Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student Student;

struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char sex;
};

Student **getstudents(int n)
{
    Student **t = malloc(sizeof *t * n); // memory for the array of pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // memory for each individual pointer
    {
        t[i] = malloc(sizeof **t);
    }
    /* Data is inputted by user with form <student> <sex> <age>, then get mapped to the struct *t */

    return t; /* Pointer to an array of pointers */
}


int main()
{
    Student **students;
    int n;
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    students = getstudents(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s, Sex: %s, Age: %d\n", students[i]->name, students[i]->sex, students[i]->age);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free(students[i]);
    }
    free(students);
    return 0;
}


I am only allowed to modify the code in `Student **getstudents(int n)`.
```

Comment: I think that you are missing some key parts of your code. For instance, what's the type of "students" in main? That's quite important because you return `Student **` from `getstudents()`, while it is in fact returning `t`, which is a `Student *`, so the problem most likely goes that way.

Comment: This code doesn't even come close to compiling. Missing semicolon, incorrect punctuation, many undefined variables (student, Data). Turn on compiler warnings and they will tell you other things that you are doing wrong.

Comment: @RaymondChen I did remove irrelevant parts and typed in manually. Let me fix them. My bad.

Comment: The declaration of `getstudents` says it is returning a `Student **` but it is returning a `Student *`. Change it to `Student *getstudents(int);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I forgot to mention that I am only allowed to modify the code inside `Student **getstudents(int n)` and not their parameters. Does that mean I should change my first line in `Student **getstudents` to a `**t` instead of a `*t`?

Comment: Of course you understood that you allocated the whole array of student structures, not an array of pointers to structures. Then you need only to use a single pointer to access the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line:

```
Student *t = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Student)*n);
```

You are allocating memory for one pointer, if you want to return a pointer to pointer, you need to allocate memory accordingly:

```
Student **t = malloc(sizeof *t * n); // memory for the array of pointers

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // memory for each individual pointer
    t[i] = malloc(sizeof **t);
}
```

To later free the pointers you also need to free each individual pointer previously allocated:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // memory for each individual pointer
    free(students[i]);
}
free(students);
```

Note that the specifier for a single character is `%c`, the printf will need to be corrected:

```
printf("Name: %s, Sex: %c, Age: %d\n", students[i]->name, students[i]->sex, students[i]->age);
//                     ^^
```

Another thing I would change is in `strncpy` instead of null terminating the string later I would let the function do it:

```
// one more byte and strncpy terminates the string for you
strncpy(t[i]->name, data[0], strlen(data[0]) + 1); 
//      ^^^^
// already corrected for the new pointer
```

---

Having corrected the issues here is a possible alternative you can use to parse all the elements in the struct with `sscanf` from `entry` in one go, if you want to:

```
Student **getstudents(int n)
{
    Student **t = malloc(sizeof *t * n); // memory for the array of pointers

    if (t == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // memory for each individual pointer
    {
        t[i] = malloc(sizeof **t);
        if (t[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char entry[100];
        if (fgets(entry, sizeof entry, stdin))
        {
            if (sscanf(entry, "%25s %c %d", t[i]->name, &t[i]->sex, &t[i]->age) != 3)
            {
                // deal with bad input
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: @CEPB, it's a matter of great debate, I don't like the cast (as you can see in my correction), because it may obfuscate errors, but I don't delve in it too much because it's opinion based.

Comment: I actually have a fix for the `strncpy` problem, but your solution is cleaner and better. Anyway, I updated the code based on your suggestions, and It still prints nothing.

Comment: @lambduh, is that right? smething else must be wrong. let me check.

Comment: The problem was that I am using `%s` for `sex` which was initialized as `char`. Credits for Zilog80 for pointing that out. I was surprised I missed that tiny detail. Anyway, code works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @lambduh, yes I noticed it, I just edited my answer with it, I have a simpler running sample if you'd like to check it out https://wandbox.org/permlink/od5rsNZoagFq3kVI

Comment: @anastaciu I think it's more simple to simply go the cmd line for that : `echo -e "Student1 M 18\nStudent2 F 19\nStudent3 M 17\nStduent4 F 18" | ./student_program`

Comment: @Zilog80 well, yes. if you have a UNIX shell :)

Comment: @anastaciu You're right. Then the Win cmd equivalent : `(echo Student1 M 18&echo Student2 F 19&echo Student3 M 17&echo Stduent4 F 18)|.\student.exe`

Comment: @Zilog80, that will do, I guess now one for powershell ;) (kidding)

Answer (score 1):

[anastaciu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66842450/3641635) points many troubles, but there is others :

Another problem in your code is that you use '%s' for the sex as sex is a only char. You should use %c or else the printf function will try to parse a string and will get a SEGFAULT.

I urge you too to stricly check every memory allocation. Always.

The revised code from my pov :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student Student;

struct student{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char sex;
};

Student **getstudents(int);
void free_students(Student**, int);

int main(){
    Student **students;
    int n = 4;
    students = getstudents(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (students[i] != NULL) {
             printf("Name: %s, Sex: %c, Age: %d\n", students[i]->name, students[i]->sex, students[i]->age);
        }
    }
    free_students(students, n);
    return 0;
}

Student **getstudents(int n){
    Student **t = (Student **)malloc(sizeof(Student *)*n);
    if (t==NULL) {
       perror("Memory: can't allocate.");
       return(NULL);
    }

    /* Input: <name> <sex> <age> */
    char entry[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        t[i]=NULL;
        if (fgets(entry,100,stdin) != NULL) {
            int readBytes = strlen(entry);
            char newString[3][25];

            int k,j,ctr;
            j=0; ctr=0;
            for(k=0;k<=readBytes;k++)
            {
                if(entry[k]==' '||entry[k]=='\0'||entry[k]=='\n')
                {
                    newString[ctr][j]='\0';
                    ctr++;
                    j=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    newString[ctr][j]=entry[k];
                    j++;
                }
            }

            t[i] = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
            if (t[i] == NULL) {
               perror("Memory: can't allocate.");
               return(NULL);
            }
            strncpy(t[i]->name, newString[0], strlen(newString[0]));
            t[i]->name[strlen(newString[0])] = '\0';
            t[i]->sex = *newString[1];
            t[i]->age = atoi(newString[2]);
       }
    }

    return t;
}

void free_students(Student **students, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(students[i]);
    }
    free(students);
}
```

Comment: Oh God I totally forgot about the `%s` for sex. After changing it, the code works.

Comment: @anastaciu As it seems to be a student work, i guess copying strlen bytes then expressly put \0 maybe more useful for student's understanding than simply copying the string plus the zero byte, no ?

Comment: I guess, as long as it's there, it's ok.